# Recyclerview glitches the borders of the items on certain phones

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have a recyclerview, each item has a colored border, everything works great on every phone except Pixel phones and some Huawey phones. It seems that on those, when scrolling down, the bottom of the border of one item attaches tot the bottom of the layout and stays there until refreshing recyclerview. It doesn't affect the items, but i see double borders on the bottom of the rv.
Any ideas how it could be happening? When removing the borders, everything works. Borders are implemented as:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="14dp"/>
</shape>
```

The item layout is just a simple linearlayout.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: i currently can't as i don't have a pixel phone.. i saw this when i tried on a friend's phone, but now he doesn't have it